# Scripting magit timing problems

Tags: emacs, elisp, magit

<kbd>C-x v =</kbd> `vc-diff` is good.  However, I can work with the diff
directly if the diff was shown in a `magit-status` buffer.

I've tried to do just that here:

```
(defvar le::vc-diff-data nil)
(defun le::magit-go-to-change-once ()
  (destructuring-bind (filename orig-buff relative-name) le::vc-diff-data
    (pop-to-buffer "*magit: magit*")
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (if (and (search-forward-regexp "^Changes:$" nil t)
             ;; WIP fix
             (progn (magit-show-level-2) t)
             (search-forward relative-name nil t))
        (progn (recenter-top-bottom 0)
               ;; WIP fix me here
               (magit-show-level-4)
               )
      ;; no diff
      (pop-to-buffer orig-buf)
      (message "no diff found.")))
  (remove-hook 'magit-refresh-status-hook #'le::magit-go-to-change-once))

(defadvice vc-diff (around magit-redirect activate compile)
  "redirect to magit"
  (let* ((vc-info (vc-deduce-fileset t))
         (filename (buffer-file-name))
         (orig-buf (current-buffer))
         (relative-name (replace-regexp-in-string
                         (concat "\\`"
                                 (regexp-quote (expand-file-name (locate-dominating-file filename ".git"))))
                         "" filename)))
    (if (string-equal "Git" (car vc-info))
        (progn
          (setq le::vc-diff-data (list filename orig-buf relative-name))
          (add-hook 'magit-refresh-status-hook #'le::magit-go-to-change-once)
          (call-interactively 'magit-status))
      ad-do-it)))
```

However the "magit-show-level*" function fails.  It works when I use
`eval-expression` in the magit buffer though.  So maybe this is a timing issue
and I have to hook in somewhere else.

Comment: Not knowing Magit very much, I don't know what you mean.  But in the long run, maybe `M-x report-emacs-bug` requesting that diff-mode incorporate some of Magit's features (and describing what those features are) might be a better option than accumulating workarounds.

Comment: I have filed a bug report for highlight space changes better in diff-refine.  But in this case, I really want to invoke magit to work with git.

Comment: The problem is that magit call the function in the hook before the section is finished, so section related function will not work there....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in my comment, the hook is called at a time when section related function will not work. You could try magit from there: https://github.com/vanicat/magit/tree/t/refresh-stasus-hook, your code should work with it.

Bye the way your proposition is interesting, and integrate it into magit contrib's proposition could be great.

Comment: very good.  that fixes it.  I'll open a PR for my functionality in contrib after this fix makes it in master.